Is penalized regression an appropriate way to analyze observational data in this space-for-time substitution study?
I am interested in understanding how a suite of response variables (soil metrics such as pH, element concentrations, rates of decomposition/minderalization, etc.) vary with 1) soil depth, and 2) time since a major disturbance (e.g., a flood, fire, hurricane, etc.).  I'd like to determine whether time or depth have a significant effect on any of the measured metrics. My hypotheses are that 1) some metrics will increase with depth, while some will decrease, and some may not change at all; 2) certain metrics will change quicker/slower than others, or not at all, with increasing time since disurbance; 3) there are similarites among sites (e.g., recently disturbed sites are similar to one another, and dissimilar to sites disturbed long ago, across depths) and 4) there are similarities among depths (e.g., surface soils are all similar to one another and dissimilar to deep soils across sites).
The design is not ideal as it lacks replication, but it goes something like this:
Suppose I've selected 10 sites (based on access permissions) from a broader group of 50 potential sites in a city/county/state/etc (to control for regional differences). I've collected a single soil core as far down as possible at each site. To understand depth-related variation, each core was collected in 10 cm increments starting at the surface (0-10 cm). Maximum sample depth varied by site due to topography and underlying geology, so depths were normalized by site (rescaled from 0-1, with 0 representing the first 10 cm and 1 representing the last 10 cm) to allow comparisons across sites.
Time since disturbance ranged from 5-100 years with some sites still actively being disturbed considered as a reference. However, I'm considering time as a continuous (not categorical) variable in my model, as I am interested in drawing conclusions on the full range of time-since-disturbance, not just what's represented in the sites I had access to. Thus, my effect terms are depth, time, and the depth*time interaction.
I'm not interested in testing whether or not my multiple response variables (soil metrics) are different--I know most of them are. Rather, I'm interested in the magnitude, direction, and rates of change in these response variables as soil depth and time-since-disturbance change. Hierarchical clustering shows which sampled depths and locations are similar/dissimilar to others, but not how the metrics vary across time and depth. I have done PCA on my response variables (soil metrics) but the variation explained along the first few principal components isn't ideal (e.g., PC1: 30%, PC2: 20%, PC3: 10%). There's no apparent collinearity among my response variables or between the predictors. Also, I can't simply compare sites via ANOVA, since each 10-cm interval is not a true replicate (i.e., observations are not independent); however, I can calculate each metric on a per-volume basis at each site resulting in a single observation at each site, though I'm not sure how useful that is because I lose the depth-related information.
Is some form of penalized regression (lasso, ridge, elastic net, etc.) the best way to analyze this kind of dataset? If not, how should I proceed?
I'm happy to provide more info or a dummy dataset if that helps. Any suggestions are welcome. Many thanks!
